# Taylor series of $(1+x)^{\frac{\ln x}{x}}$ at $0^{+}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I want to find the Taylor series of $(1+x)^{\frac{\ln x}{x}}$ at $0^{+}$.

I already found that $(1+x)^{\large\frac{\ln x}x}=x-\frac{x^2 \ln x}{2} +o(x^2 \ln x)$ but I'm struggling to get a better precision.

Here is what I did:

using the classic Taylor series of $\ln(1+x)$ at $0$ we have that

$\ln x\:\frac{\ln (1+x)}x=\ln x-\frac{x\ln x}2+o(x\ln x)$.

As $(1+x)^{\large\frac{\ln x}x}=e^{\ln x-\frac{x\ln x}2++o(x\ln x)}$, we find

$(1+x)^{\large\frac{\ln x}x}=e^{\large \ln x} \cdot e^{-\frac{x\ln x}2+o(x\ln x)}=x (1- \frac{x \ln x}{2}+o(x\ln x))$ and the result follows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot have a Taylor series at $0$ because the function is not analytic at $0$. What you can obtain is something called a transseries (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transseries).

Comment: Check here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+series+%281%2Bx%29%5E%28ln%28x%29%2Fx%29+at+x%3D0

Comment: If you are interested in a good approximation I suspect that keeping the exponential will give better results.

Comment: @lcv what do you mean by keeping the exponential ?

Comment: I mean writing your expression (as you did at the baginning) as $e^{\mathrm{blah}}$ and then expand "blah"

Answer (score 1):

For a more precision, this expansion can help:

$$x-\frac{1}{2} x^2 \ln (x)+\frac{1}{24} x^3 \left(3 \ln ^2(x)+8 \ln (x)\right)+\frac{1}{48} x^4 \left(-\ln ^3(x)-8 \ln ^2(x)-12 \ln (x)\right)+\frac{x^5 \left(15 \ln ^4(x)+240 \ln ^3(x)+1040 \ln ^2(x)+1152 \ln (x)\right)}{5760}+O\left(x^6\right)$$

I will add details in a while, after getting off the bus.